# Paypal Integration PHP Laravel - Get transaction ID

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, payment-gateway

I'm using laravel framework. I want to add Paypal integration in my app. 
Customer can pay with me this code,

```
    <form action="{{$paypal_url}}" method="post" name="frmPayPal1">
      <input type="hidden" name="business" value="{{$paypal_id;}}">
      <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
      <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Mangalayojana PREMIUM package">
      <!--<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">-->
      <!--<input type="hidden" name="credits" value="510">-->
      <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="{{Auth::id()}}">
      <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1.05">
      <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="header_image" value="demo.ceylonsystems.com/img/logo.png">
      <!--<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">-->
      <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
      <input type="hidden" name="handling" value="0">
      <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://demo.ceylonsystems.com/upgrade?state=notcompleted">
      <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://mangalayojana.div.lk/payments.php">
      <input type="hidden" name="thanks_page" value="http://mangalayojana.div.lk/payments.php">
   </form>
```

I want to receive transaction ID from paypal server. How can I do it, Any idea guys?

Comment: There are packages for this problem. Have you checked them out already?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to handle post transaction processing with PayPal is to use Instant [Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/).  There are Laravel packages for IPN available on GitHub / Packagist.

As a side note, if you ever find yourself wanting to integrate PayPal API's into your Laravel projects you may be interested in my [PHP class library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library).  It is also available on GitHub and Packagist and makes integrating PayPal into Laravel (and any PHP platform for that matter) very simple.